# How secure is setting mongodb to 0.0.0.0 but blocking all incoming requests to 27017 on ec2?

Tags: amazon-ec2, mongodb

As the title suggests. If I set the `net.bindIp` setting in mongod.conf to 0.0.0.0 on port 27017 this should open it up to all incoming connections. However, if in my ec2 instance I whitelist only my local IP on 27017 will this block all other incoming connections?

I should also note I have a mongodb user with a password set for my db with `security.authorization: 'enabled'` also set in mongod.conf

Asking for a friend... Thanks

Also please, point me to the correct stackexchange if this is off topic

Answer (score 1):

I didn't get exactly what your friend is trying to do but what can i say is :

Setting net.bindIp to 0.0.0.0 is the same as setting net.bindIpAll to ***true*** this will make your server listening on all your available network interfaces on port 27017.

That means that your mongodb instance will be reachable from all networks that can reach your NICs.

Whitelisting only your local ip on 27017 means using security group rules to allow only the inbound ( I guess ) traffic on 127.0.0.1:27017. So if this is the case that means your mongodb instance will be reachable only from your localhost.

Also setting *security.authorization: 'enabled'* will enable ***Access Control*** which wil enforce authentication to your databases using a user and a password.

Comment: I haven't been able to figure out "recommended practice" for setting up access to mongo This is the only thing I've been able to come up with

Comment: And it's me.. I'm the friend

Comment: But with what you're saying it seems that only the people I allow on the inbound security group rules should in theory be able to access my mongo database. Because I lied a little bit. I need two IPs plus localhost able to connect to my db. This was the only way I could figure out how with relative ease.

Comment: So you have to whitelist only those needed IPs. Check the following link in order to secure your mongodb instance https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-secure-mongodb-nosql-production-database/